# Why is my drive showing almost 1TB usage when I just now created the partition?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ext4

I just now got done wiping an 18TB drive, formatting it, making a new partition, and creating the filesystem on it. Below is the output of `df -h` on another machine that's connected via Samba.

```
//192.168.1.231/Dock4   17T  839G   16T   6% /media/Dock4
```

Where is that 6%/839GB coming from?

Comment: this is capitalism